# How do I handle server requests that I don't want on a rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

My server gets a lot of requests for things it doesn't have, like: apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png. In the interest of conserving CPU, what is the best way to cut off processing these request as high up the chain as possible? Is there a gem that would allow me to easily add "abort" routes to my app?

I'm on Heroku, btw, if that would influence recommendations...

The only thing I can think to do ATM is add to my routes file.

Comment: I am curious as to why this is happening in the first place.

Comment: Browsers request certain resources by default. Like favicon.ico for instance. This looks like an iOS device running Safari, requesting potential resources to use on say the home screen or something like that.